# How does SVG affect border rendering in Chrome 60 / Windows 7?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, svg, rendering, border

Exact chrome version: 60.0.3112.113 64bit.

It happens on my Windows 7 desktop, but I can't reproduce it on my Windows 10 laptop.

This code works fine:

```
<button style="border-radius: 17px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px">
    Button
</button>
```

Result:

[image: normal result]

But if I add this SVG to the document:

```
<svg>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
    <path d="M0 0c0-4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 60"></path>
</svg>
```

The result becomes weird:

[image: aliased result]

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q29aofrm/

This is simplified SVG code. And not any SVG produce side effects. A real example I found at http://getbootstrap.com/ (look closely at button corners)

Can you explain that strange behavior?
Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Maybe it's my eyes but the weird button looks the same as the normal one.

Comment: @RobertLongson, [here](http://telegra.ph/file/12d99aa950a8a548fdf35.png) is zoomed version

Comment: That's just artifacts of Chrome's antialiasing. I suspect there's nothing you can do about it.